# How to log MongoDB connection errors in a Nest.js application

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

We're migrating our microservices from an on-premises server farm to an IaaS environment through a public cloud provider.  One of our services is based on Nest.js, and has been running fine for years in our on-premises servers.  Now, however, when run in the IaaS environment, it is no longer able to connect to MongoDB.  Our other microservices, based on different frameworks, work just fine.

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but on our on-premises server, MongoDB was at version 3.6, whereas on the IaaS environment, it is 5.0.

The error seen in the logs is:

```
[Nest] 1  - 05/02/2023, 8:12:47 PM   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
[Nest] 1  - 05/02/2023, 8:13:20 PM   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)...
```

We are using `@nestjs/mongoose` to connect to MongoDB.  Our connection code, in `app.module.ts` looks like:

```
function getDbConnectionString() {
  const dbConnectionString = `${process.env.MONGO_URL}&tlsCAFile=/etc/mongo-cert/mongoCA.pem&tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true`;

  const logger = new Logger('AppModule');
  logger.log(`DB Connection string: ${dbConnectionString}`);

  return dbConnectionString;
}

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(getDbConnectionString()),
    HealthModule,
    HttpModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

At this point, I mainly want to direct the connection errors to a log file to get an idea of what the connection issue is.  Unfortunately, after much searching, I've not been able to figure out how to do that.

So, my question is, how can connection errors from Mongoose in a Nest.js application be logged?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing an `options` object, to the `forRoot` function like this:

```
  MongooseModule.forRoot(dbURL, {
      connectionFactory: (connection) => {
        connection.on('connected', () => {
           console.log('is connected');
        });
        connection.on('disconnected', () => {
           console.log('DB disconnected');
        });
        connection.on('error', (error) => {
           console.log('DB connection failed! for error: ', error);
        });
        return connection;
        },
      },
    );
```

Comment: I do have a `connectionFactory`, but it isn't returning anything.  I recall reading somewhere that the error callback is only called once a connection is established.

Comment: Oh, I was unaware of that, most likely, I think either your database is unavailable or the database URI is wrong, check them carefully

Answer (score 0):

**@Charchit Kapoor** forgot to add `connection._events.connected();`. Try this:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    Mongoose.forRoot(dbURL, {
      connectionFactory: connection => {
        connection.on('connected', () => {
          console.log('is connected');
        });
        connection.on('disconnected', () => {
          console.log('DB disconnected');
        });
        connection.on('error', error => {
          console.log('DB connection failed! for error: ', error);
        });
        connection._events.connected();
        return connection;
      },
    }),
  ],
})
```